# Java app on windows 8 tablet being killed when screen turns off

Tags: java, windows, windows-8, tablet

We had to write a Java application which runs on a windows 8 tablet (*not RT*).

I would much rather have written it using C#, but we really didn't have a choice.

Basically, we use launch4j to wrap our installer executable JAR in an EXE which then installs the appropriate application files and creates shortcuts on the desktop and in the start menu programs folder to ensure that the user sees the icons on the metro start screen.

---

**The Problem**

When the application starts up, it checks if any updates are available via a server, if they are available they are downloaded.

The issue that we've seen is that if the application is downloading the updates, and then we turn off the screen and leave it off for at least 30 seconds, once we turn the screen back on, the application is frozen and does not progress.
We then have to kill the app and start it again.
Providing the screen is not turned off again, the downloads finish and the application works fine.

Is there a way to either keep the screen on, keep our process running or detect when the screen comes back on and execute some code when that occurs?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the app only die if it's in the middle of downloading updates when the screen turns off?  If that's the case, could this behavior just be a failure mode of whatever networking library you're using to do the download, or are you certain that Windows8 is actively killing the app?  Can you add a timeout to the portion of the code that performs the download?

Comment: It only appears to occur during the download. If I let the download finish, turn the screen off, wait at least 30 seconds and then turn the screen back on... the app response as expected. I guess I'll look into the actual connection being created; see if I can put some timeout.

Comment: I should add that the download does stop while the screen is off... and providing the screen isn't off for too long, it continues. I does sound like some kind of timeout issue :(